# Abstract attributes in Python

Tags: python, oop, scala, abstract-class

What is the shortest / most elegant way to implement the following Scala code with an abstract attribute in Python?

```
abstract class Controller {

    val path: String

}
```

A subclass of `Controller` is enforced to define "path" by the Scala compiler. A subclass would look like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller {

    override val path = "/home"

}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post your Python code with any problems or question you have about your solution.

Comment: "A subclass of Controller is enforced to define "path" by the Scala compiler." ... Enforced when? If it's compile time, you're out of luck. If it's runtime, then how exactly do you want it "enforced"? In other words, is there a difference between raising an AttributeError and a NotImplementedError? Why?

Comment: I know that Python is a dynamic language and that the python interpreter cannot enforce static types. It is important to me, that it fails as early as possibly and that it is easy to find the place where the error orrured and why.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151212/equivalent-of-notimplementederror-for-fields-in-python

Comment: There are some relevant answers to a newer duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831510/abstract-attribute-not-property, but basically the takeaway is that as of python 3.8 there is no nice solution.

Comment: Attributes (simple class assignments such as `foo = 1` and docstrings) are different to properties (which emulate attribute access via methods). This question about *attributes* should not be marked as a duplicate of a question about *properties*.

Comment: As Tyson mentioned, this is not a duplicate: it was about attributes, not properties.  If it is to be listed as a duplicate, it should be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831510/abstract-attribute-not-property, not the unhelpful question linked to at the moment.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Python has a built-in exception for this, though you won't encounter the exception until runtime.

```
class Base(object):
    @property
    def path(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class SubClass(Base):
    path = 'blah'
```

Comment: Specifically, you won't encounter the exception until the attrtibute is accessed, in which case you would have got an AttributeError anyway.

Comment: I think that raising a `NotImplementedError` is more explicit and therefore probably better than leaving it to an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Also you can add a message such "Can't instantiate abstract class Base" when raising an exception yourself.

Comment: Not that this only works if `path` is set directly on the `SubClass`. Given an instance `sc = SubClass()`, if you try to set `sc.path = 'blah'` or have a method that contains something like `self.path = 'blah'` without defining `path` directly on `SubClass`, you will get an `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Comment: How to provide the abstract property a default value?

Comment: It is not the answer!!  This is not instance field. Scala filed in class is instance field because Scala separate the static and instance.

Comment: should be `raise NotImplementedError()` otherwise you just raise the type as the exception not the exception object itself.

Comment: @Simmovation see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707102/308451

Comment: above solution using abc module enforces that sub-classes override!

Comment: This also triggers type checkers as an error due to incompatible overrides.  Not recommended (in 2023).

Answer (score 173):

### Python 3.3+

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def a(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def b(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    a = 1

    def b(self):
        pass
```

Failure to declare `a` or `b` in the derived class `B` will raise a `TypeError` such as:

> `TypeError`: Can't instantiate abstract class `B` with abstract methods `a`

### Python 2.7

There is an [@abstractproperty](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty) decorator for this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty


class A:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def a(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def b(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    a = 1

    def b(self):
        pass
```

Comment: My "A" class is a subclass of Exception, and this appears to break the example.

Comment: @Chris2048 how does it break it? what error are you getting?

Comment: Is there a way to write this in a Python 2/3 agnostic way similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673474/using-abc-abcmeta-in-a-way-it-is-compatible-both-with-python-2-7-and-python-3-5)?

Comment: Your python 3 solution implements `a` as a class-property of `B`, instead of an object property. If you instead do
```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
    ...
```
you get an error when instantiating `B`:
"Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods a"

Comment: @Janus makes an important point ... being able to `class MyController(val path: String) extends Controller` is a valuable option available in the scala version but missing here

Comment: I don0t know why I don't get any error when creating class B without property `a` . `class B(A):

    def b(self):
        pass`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330411/my-abstractclass-contructor-do-not-raise-and-error-not-error-when-missing-proper

Comment: This doesn't pass typechecking for me: literal cannot be assigned to declared type 'property'

Answer (score 119):

Since this question was originally asked, python has changed how abstract classes are implemented. I have used a slightly different approach using the abc.ABC formalism in python 3.6.  Here I define the constant as a property which must be defined in each subclass.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Base(ABC):

    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def CONSTANT(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def print_constant(self):
        print(type(self).CONSTANT)


class Derived(Base):
    CONSTANT = 42
```

This forces the derived class to define the constant, or else a `TypeError` exception will be raised when you try to instantiate the subclass. When you want to use the constant for any functionality implemented in the abstract class, you must access the subclass constant by `type(self).CONSTANT` instead of just `CONSTANT`, since the value is undefined in the base class.

There are other ways to implement this, but I like this syntax as it seems to me the most plain and obvious for the reader.

The previous answers all touched useful points, but I feel the accepted answer does not directly answer the question because

- The question asks for implementation in an abstract class, but the accepted answer does not follow the abstract formalism.
- The question asks that implementation is enforced.  I would argue that enforcement is stricter in this answer because it causes a runtime error when the subclass is instantiated if `CONSTANT` is not defined. The accepted answer allows the object to be instantiated and only throws an error when `CONSTANT` is accessed, making the enforcement less strict.

This is not to fault the original answers.  Major changes to the abstract class syntax have occurred since they were posted, which in this case allow a neater and more functional implementation.

Comment: this appears to be the only correct answer which also appeases `mypy`

Comment: Thank you for one of the only answers that *actually* addresses the question. Can I ask what the purpose of the `print_constant` method is? As far as I can tell it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Here you can't call it without instantiating the Derived class. Thus no difference if you remove @classmethod decorator

Comment: I had looked up this question before and never noticed your answer. It should be the accepted one, if I had known this was possible to stack `@property` and `@classmethod` decorators I would've used that long ago. Thank you

Comment: what if you want to initialize `CONSTANT` according to user input?

Comment: @BrianJoseph - The `print_constant` method is there to illustrate how to access the constant in the parent class, given that it is only defined in the child class

Comment: *Since this question was originally asked, python has changed how abstract classes are implemented.* – could you please specify what change do you refer to here?

Comment: What is the point of including the `@classmethod` decorator? Isn't this unnecessary?

Comment: I thought that by making it a `@classmethod`, it'd essentially be an abstract class attribute. However, its definition in subclasses is not enforced if accessed on the type rather than an instance of the subclass - the former just returns a property object. To get such behaviour, `__init_subclass__` would be more appropriate.

Comment: If you add a return type declaration to the definition of `Base.CONSTANT` then mypy will also check that the subclass uses the right type for the definition of `CONSTANT`.

Comment: be aware, throwing TypeError when instantiated only happens if the Python compiler/interpreter supports it, so e.g. it does work with CPython (tested with `GCC 9.3.0`), but may not work on some others (I know of at least 1 online testing page when this does not throw an error)

Comment: `self.CONSTANT` will do as well, instead of `type(self).CONSTANT`.

Comment: FYI: due to the way the decorators interact, `@classmethod` should be on top of `@property`

Comment: Thanks @Mason3k - I made an edit so now `@classmethod` precedes `@property`

Comment: What is the point of returning `NotImplementedError`? Why not raise it or return `NotImplemented`(returning `NotImplemented` also has no effect, I think)?

Comment: Thank you Boseong, you are right that raising the error is the correct thing to do. I will edit the answer to reflect this. Regarding the option of returning `NotImplemented`, my understanding is that this is only done for comparison operators.

Comment: I can confirm what @JonathanScholbach said: `type(self).CONSTANT` is not needed, just use `self.CONSTANT`. @James did we miss anything here? If not, you could improve the answer even more :)

Comment: As a note, [stacking `@classmethod` and `@property` seems to be deprecated as of Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#classmethod) (and yes, it was just introduced in Python 3.9). See [this answer on a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64738850/8754471) for a bit of discussion and some relevant links.

Answer (score 82):

[In Python 3.6+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), you can annotate an attribute of an abstract class (or any variable) without providing a value for that attribute.

```py
from abc import ABC

class Controller(ABC):
    path: str

class MyController(Controller):
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self.path = path
```

This makes for very clean code where it is obvious that the attribute is abstract.

It should be noted that this will not raise an exception at definition time if a subclass does not provide an implementation. However, an `AttributeError` exception will be raised if anythhing tries to access the undefined attribute.

Comment: In Python 3.7 i dont get any errors if MyController is define without path property.  Why?

Comment: @DaniTeba This solution raises and error at access time, not definition time. You would have to use one of the decorator solutions if raising the error at class definition time is important to you.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution that passes type-checking too.

Comment: This is not appropriate. These are completely different categories of attributes.
`Controller.path` is an attribute of the class, this shared among instances (equivalent to `static` attributes  in `C#`). `MyController().path` is an atribute of the instance.

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli Are you sure? I'm using Python 3.9 with the example above, and I can see that `path` is an _annotation_ of the `Controller` class (in `Controller.__dict__`), but trying to use `Controller.path` is an attribute error: `AttributeError: type object 'Controller' has no attribute 'path'`. 

Even if the `path` assignment was removed in the `MyController` init method, instances of it still wouldn't have the `path` attribute and would raise the same attribute error

Answer (score 32):

You could create an attribute in the [abc.ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC) abstract base class with a value such as [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=notimplemented#the-notimplemented-object) so that if the attribute is not overriden and then used, a clear error that expresses intent is shown at run time.

The following code uses a [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) type hint to help PyCharm correctly statically analyze the type of the `path` attribute as well.

```py
from abc import ABC

class Controller(ABC):
    path: str = NotImplemented

class MyController(Controller):
    path = "/home"
```

Comment: Note this is not instance field. The Scala field is always instance member in the class definition. Because Scala separate the static and instance.

Comment: Note this is abusing `NotImplemented` that is there for a different purpose. This was my idea too, so I kind of approve though ^^ I think @drhagen's answer is more correct, but using `= NotImplemented` is way more visible.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but even without this, if an attribute is used and not overriden or defined, it will throw an error. It's basic behaviour for any class.

Comment: @Corel the idea is that this makes the intent very explicit and discoverable.

Answer (score 26):

As of Python 3.6 you can use `__init_subclass__` to check for the class variables of the child class upon initialisation:

```py
from abc import ABC

class A(ABC):
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        required_class_variables = [
            'foo',
            'bar',
        ]
        for var in required_class_variables:
            if not hasattr(cls, var):
                raise NotImplementedError(
                    f'Class {cls} lacks required `{var}` class attribute'
                )
```

This raises an Error on initialisation of the child class, if the missing class variable is not defined, so you don't have to wait until the missing class variable would be accessed.

Comment: `__init_subclass__` of the parent class is called before the subclass is initialised. So if you want to check for properties set in the subclass's `__init__`, this won't work.

Comment: @notnami That is true. However, the question asks for class variables, not for instance variables which would be set during the `__init__` method.

Comment: Hum... Is it me or are you the only one to strictly address the question ? :) +1.

Answer (score 25):

For **Python 3.3**+ there's an elegant solution

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
    
class BaseController(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def path(self) -> str:
        ...

class Controller(BaseController):
    path = "/home"


# Instead of an elipsis, you can add a docstring for clarity
class AnotherBaseController(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def path(self) -> str:
        """
        :return: the url path of this controller
        """
```

Despite some great answers have already been given, I thought this answer would nevertheless add some value. This approach has two advantages:

1. `...` in an abstract method's body is more preferable than `pass`. Unlike `pass`, `...` implies **no operations**, where `pass` only means the absence of an actual implementation
2. `...` is more recommended than throwing `NotImplementedError(...)`. This automatically prompts an extremely verbose error if the implementation of an abstract field is missing in a subclass. In contrast, `NotImplementedError` itself doesn't tell why the implementation is missing. Moreover, it requires manual labor to actually raise it.

Comment: Your point #2 is not correct. Whether you type `...` or raise `NotImplementedError` or simply `pass` has no impact on the error raised when trying to instantiate an abstract class (or subclass) with unimplemented methods.

Comment: And when you raise NotImplementedError you can pass a string message to tell more detailed information to the caller about why the error is being thrown.

Comment: Instead of `pass` or an elipsis (`...`) it's better to declare at least a docstring for the abstract method. pylint told me that.

Comment: Thanks sausix, it's a good point. I'll include it into the answer

Answer (score 11):

I've modified just a bit [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53417582/4601890) answer, so that all those decorators do not take so much place. If you had multiple such abstract properties to define, this is handy:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

def abstractproperty(func):
   return property(classmethod(abstractmethod(func)))

class Base(ABC):

    @abstractproperty
    def CONSTANT(cls): ...

    def print_constant(self):
        print(type(self).CONSTANT)


class Derived(Base):
    CONSTANT = 42

class BadDerived(Base):
    BAD_CONSTANT = 42

Derived()       # -> Fine
BadDerived()    # -> Error
```

Comment: The one line `abstractproperty` looks very useful, but it gives me an error on Python 3.10 and Pylance:

Argument of type "classmethod[Unknown]" cannot be assigned to parameter "fget" of type "((Any) -> Any) | None" in function "__init__"
  Type "classmethod[Unknown]" cannot be assigned to type "((Any) -> Any) | None"
    Type "classmethod[Unknown]" cannot be assigned to type "(Any) -> Any"
    Type cannot be assigned to type "None"

Comment: @JanDolejsi I have tested it on the [online python 3.11 tool](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) and it works. Maybe some python 3.10 bug?

Answer (score 7):

Python3.6 implementation might looks like this:

```
In [20]: class X:
    ...:     def __init_subclass__(cls):
    ...:         if not hasattr(cls, 'required'):
    ...:             raise NotImplementedError

In [21]: class Y(X):
    ...:     required = 5
    ...:     

In [22]: Y()
Out[22]: <__main__.Y at 0x7f08408c9a20>
```

Comment: Not sure this will raise a type error though if your subclasses don't implement the attribute, in case you're using type checking from an IDE

Answer (score 5):

Your base class could implement a `__new__` method that check for class attribute:

```
class Controller(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kargs):
        if not hasattr(cls,'path'): 
            raise NotImplementedError("'Controller' subclasses should have a 'path' attribute")
        return object.__new__(cls)

class C1(Controller):
    path = 42

class C2(Controller):
    pass


c1 = C1() 
# ok

c2 = C2()  
# NotImplementedError: 'Controller' subclasses should have a 'path' attribute
```

This way the error raise at instantiation

Comment: interestingly, this doesn't work if you need to use def __init__(self).

Answer (score 1):

```
class AbstractStuff:
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def some_property(self):
        pass
```

As of 3.3 `abc.abstractproperty` is deprecated, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Bastien Léonard's answer mentions the abstract base class module and Brendan Abel's answer deals with non-implemented attributes raising errors. To ensure that the class is not implemented outside of the module, you could prefix the base name with an underscore which denotes it as private to the module (i.e. it is not imported).

i.e.

```
class _Controller(object):
    path = '' # There are better ways to declare attributes - see other answers

class MyController(_Controller):
    path = '/Home'
```

Comment: is it possible to raise some error if the subclass does not redefine the attribute? It would be easy for methods, but how about attributes?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to leave out the path declaration in `_Controller` class? Duck Typing wouldn't take effect if there is already a (invalid) value. Otherwise at some point, where I need the `path` field to be defined, there would be no error because there is already a value.

Comment: @Mario - yes, Brendan Abel's answer gives a good way to do this

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the abc (Abtract Base Class) module: http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html

However, in my opinion the simplest and most common solution is to raise an exception when an instance of the base class is created, or when its property is accessed.

Comment: Please elaborate: How does abc module help in this context?