# How to define lazy variable in Python which will raise NotImplementedError for abstract code skeleton?

Tags: python

I want to define some constants in class which will be define in class instance (derived classes) - how to signal error if this variables is not redefine in children classes? I want to raise `NotImplementedError` on first read.

```
class Parent(object):
   abstract_variable = ?

   # I want achieve same behavior for variable
   def abstract_function(self):
     raise NotImplementedError()

class Child(Parent):
   def __init__():
     # should throw NotImplementedError() on read
     print self.abstract_variable
```

Is it possible to do it in one line?

```
abstract_variable = ?
```

Comment: Take a look at [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/abc.html).

Comment: Do you want the child classes to override the parent with a class variable, or an instance variable? That is, what would `Child` look like if it was doing it right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, the clearest would be to not do anything in the parent class.
Then when reading you'd just get an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: Child instance has no attribute 'abstract_variable'
```

Or in the parent class you can have a `property` which raises `NotImplementedError` **and** overwrite it with a `property` with getter and setter in each child class; or in the child class set the value to `None` in the class body...

---

However if you want to raise `NotImplementedError`, you can make a *non-data* descriptor (that is, a [descriptor class](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) *without* `__set__`, a `property` always has `__set__`). This allows you to set the value in the subclass.

The most straightforward way to do it is

```
class abstract_attribute(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        raise NotImplementedError("This attribute was not set in a subclass")
```

And you use it like

```
class Parent(object):
    variable = abstract_attribute()

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            print(self.variable)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Got error %s" % e)

        self.variable = 42
        print(self.variable)

Child()
```

Which outputs

```
Got error This attribute was not set in a subclass
42
```

A `property` does not make it possible to set the value as easily as with my `abstract_attribute`.

---

But wait, we can make it a bit more magic: the descriptor can find out *which* attribute it was accessed from:

```
class abstract_attribute(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, type):   
        # Now we will iterate over the names on the class,
        # and all its superclasses, and try to find the attribute
        # name for this descriptor
        # traverse the parents in the method resolution order
        for cls in type.__mro__:
            # for each cls thus, see what attributes they set
            for name, value in cls.__dict__.items():
                # we found ourselves here
                if value is self:
                    # if the property gets accessed as Child.variable,
                    # obj will be done. For this case
                    # If accessed as a_child.variable, the class Child is 
                    # in the type, and a_child in the obj.
                    this_obj = obj if obj else type

                    raise NotImplementedError(
                         "%r does not have the attribute %r "
                         "(abstract from class %r)" %
                             (this_obj, name, cls.__name__))

        # we did not find a match, should be rare, but prepare for it
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "%s does not set the abstract attribute <unknown>", type.__name__)
```

With this code, accessing `self.variable` raises the exception with a very informative message:

```
NotImplementedError: <__main__.Child object at 0x7f7c7a5dd860> does not
have the attribute 'variable' (abstract from class 'Parent')
```

and `Child.variable` gives

```
NotImplementedError: <class '__main__.Child'> does not have the 
attribute 'variable' (abstract from class 'Parent')
```

Comment: It looks very promising I will test soon. It looks it is exactly what is need. Thank you very much for answering I will accept question after first tests. Especially nice is polymorphism with mro with I often using too.

Answer (score 3):

Please see [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536176/how-to-define-lazy-variable-in-python-which-will-raise-notimplementederror-for-a/32536493#32536493)'s answer, he provides a better answer.

Use the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) function as a decorator

```
class Parent(object):
   @property
   def abstract_variable(self):
     raise NotImplementedError()
```

Getting `instance.abstract_variable` will then throw a `NotImplementedError`.