# How to declare a variable to be implemented in the subclass in python?

Tags: python

### Update

Actually, I have tested all the answers, but a feature I want still can't be achieved. Using `@property` force the subclass to directly declare the property but not something like `self.property = xxx` in one function. How could I also achieve this?

I mean, if the subclass `__get__` the property before `__set__`, then raise `NotImplementedError`.

---

How to declare a variable in the super class which should be implemented in the subclass?

In other word, I want to declare a virtual variable in super class.

```
class A:

    def a(self):               # perfect!
        raise NotImplementedError("...") 

    b = raise NotImplementedError("...")      #how to declare a variable similar with the function above?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python doesn't really have something called virtual objects, you can mimic in case of methods by explicitly raising exception but in the case of variables, you can either override `__init__` or use properties instead of variables.

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self, 'b'):
            raise NotImplementedError("...")

class B(A):
    b = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `property` decorator. For more information, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536176/how-to-define-lazy-variable-in-python-which-will-raise-notimplementederror-for-a) where you can get a detailed answer.