# implement inheritance class with static variable - python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, static

I want to to implement some classes with the same static variables for the all classes. I want to restrict those classes to have same structure. so I want to use abstract class. but I have problem to achieve this methodology with abstract class.
those variables need to be static because there isn't situation those variables change. I just want to "collect" some variable "under the same roof"

example:

```
class FirstChild(Father):
     first_static_variable = "value to first_static_variable in first child"
     second_static_variable = "value to second_static_variable in first child"


class SecondChild(Father):
     first_static_variable = "value to first_static_variable in second child"
     second_static_variable = "value to second_static_variable in second child"


class Father(ABC):
     #here I want to force Father childs to have first_static_variable and second_static_variable
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but maybe use a tuple.

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Abstract attribute (not property)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831510/abstract-attribute-not-property)

Comment: Can you show a circumstance where something fails because one of the child classes has failed to define one of its static variables? (aka class attributes)

Comment: I want to direct the next programmer to implement similar class with those variables. There is script that run and do
Child.first_static_variable
And I don't this script to fail.