# Abstract class attribute in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, class-attributes

I have a class like this

```
from abc import ABC

class AbstractFoo(ABC):
  # Subclasses are expected to specify this
  # Yes, this is a class attribute, not an instance attribute
  bar: list[str] = NotImplemented  

# for example
class SpecialFoo(AbstractFoo):
  bar = ["a", "b"]
```

But this does not feel particularly clean and perhaps a little confusing. Importantly, the `bar` attribute is nowhere marked as abstract, so it could be still possible to instantiate it without being specified. Is there a better way to achieve a similar behavior?

Comment: This is just something that Python ABCs don't support. But you may find this recipe for an 'abstractproperty' does what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/42529760/202168 ...by defining a not-implemented abstractproperty on the ABC it can be overridden with a regular class attribute on sub-classes, and if not overridden will give an "TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class X with abstract method required" when trying to instantiate the sub-class

Answer (score 1):

Just don't specify a value, to keep it as an annotation?

```
from abc import ABC

class AbstractFoo(ABC):
  bar: list[str] 


class SpecialFoo(AbstractFoo):
  bar = ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: But then I can still instantiate `AbstractFoo` which I consider somewhat undesirable. - It raises an `AttributeError` at runtime, rather then a `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class AbstractFoo ...` kind of error when reading the class.

Comment: Even a subclass that doesn't specify `bar` is instantiable.