# Making a class abstract the old way wont work

Tags: python, abc

I am trying to create an abstract base class.
When using the syntax of python 3, it work perfectly.
But then when I switch to the syntax of python 2.7 it just wont work.

the following code is written in 2.7 syntax, and if I run it, it will work, when it shouldn't, there is no `foo` method in the `StillAbstract` class.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Abstract:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass


class StillAbstract(Abstract):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = StillAbstract()
```

But then when I write it in a 3+ syntax, it works the way it should, failing with an error that the abstract base class gives.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Abstract(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass


class StillAbstract(Abstract):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = StillAbstract()
```

Any idea why it work that way?

Comment: Another dupe candidate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35673474/4636715

Comment: Thanks for the reference, could not find it -_-