# Define private variable of class as abstract

Tags: python, python-2.7, abstract-class, abc

I want to know what is the correct way to make my class's private variables as abstract. Let me summarize the properties of my variable:

- Class variable
- private
- abstract

Structure of my classes is like:

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class AbstractClass(ABCMeta):
    __private_abstract_property = None   # Needs this as private abstract class variable
    # ... some functions


class ParentClass(AbstractClass):   # inherits `AbstractClass`
    # .. some more functions


class ChildClass1(ParentClass):    # inherits `ParentClass`
    __private_abstract_property = 'value1'   # value to be initialized here


class ChildClass2(ParentClass):    # inherits `ParentClass`
    __private_abstract_property = 'value2'
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

One way is to use [`abc.abstractproperty`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty) decorator as:

```
class AbstractClass(ABCMeta):
    @abstractproperty
    def __private_abstract_property(self):
        ...
```

Or, as mentioned in answers to [Abstract Attributes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38732834/2063361) as:

```
class AbstractClass(ABCMeta):
    __private_abstract_property = NotImplemented
```

I want to know the right way to achieve this (any approach even apart from what I mentioned is welcomed).

---

**Edit:** Here is some description of what I am trying to do:

- I have a manager `AbstractClass` which has some set operation related to the database. It should be abstract as I do not want any direct object of this class. Also it has some functions with no definition
- `ParentClass` is derived from the `AbstractClass`. It will have some set of function related to fetching particular items from database. Again this class also don't know about the database it is dealing with.
- The `ChildClass` will be actually having the database engine with which it should interact with. As there can be different engines holding same kind of information, I will set the connection name here and based on this connection as source, `ParentClass`'s function will fetch information from database. Also, `ChildClass` can have additional functions apart from `ParentClass`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) precipitated by an attempt to write Java in Python. What task are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Made an edit in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *no privacy model* in Python. Double-underscore names are not private in the sense that a Java or C# name is private; such names are *class private*.

Class private means they are protected (by prefixing their name with the class name) from accidental overriding in a subclass. This means that there is **absolutely no point** in putting double-underscore names in an abstract class; subclasses should never use the exact same name.

See the [*Reserved classes of identifiers* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) part of the reference documentation:

> `__*`
>   Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and derived classes.

You should not put *anything* private in a abstract base class anyway. ABCs are akin to interfaces, documenting the *public* API subclasses should provide.

So, even if you gave names a *single* leading underscore (signalling, by convention only, that a name is part of the internal implementation and can't be relied upon to remain available in other implementations or future versions), these should not be part of an ABC; it is not the purview of an abstract base class to dictate how subclasses implement the methods and properties proscribed.

Comment: Ok, Let's say if I am okay with going with public variable (by convention), then I should be using `@abstractproperty` property decorator?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: yes, then you can document that you want an attribute with `@abstractproperty`. Note that there is no enforcement how things are implemented, only that the name is there, for both `@abstractmethod` and `@abstractproperty`.

Comment: But in that case it will be instance variable, but I want it to be class variable. I made an edit in the question at the last. May be it will help you understand what I am trying to do

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: no, abstract classes say nothing about instance vs class variables, just that the name needs to exist.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: your `ParentClass` and `ChildClass` classes are *implementations*. If `ParentClass` needs a certain name to be set on the class, then that's an implementation detail. That's not part of the public interface of the ABC.