# How to declare abstract class static fields in Python?

Tags: python, generics, abstract-class, metaprogramming

> I'm not a native English speaker, so please try to avoid abbreviations or slang in your answers.

I want to try to declare an abstract class field in a Python base class.

I know that python can declare an abstract object field via `@property` and `@abstractmethod`, but I haven't checked for a viable abstract class field.

I want to be able to implement such use case:

```py
class AbcClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractproperty
    class_field: int # class-level static field

# inherite abstract class
class MyClass(AbcClass):
    class_field = 42
```

About related thread:

[Python: Create Abstract Static Property within Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022656/python-create-abstract-static-property-within-class): This post does give some viable options, but since I'm trying metaprogramming, using `__init_subclass__` causes IDE support to become difficult.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Create Abstract Static Property within Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022656/python-create-abstract-static-property-within-class)

Comment: @sowmya I've already read that thread, but I'm wondering if there's a better (especially more IDE-friendly) solution. Overriding `__init_subclass__` is not ideal for IDE hints.