# Python: how to make abstract class attribute, with all caps naming convention and linter warnings

Tags: python, oop, abstract, abstract-methods, class-attributes

I have an abstract base class, with a constant class attribute.

How can I force a child class to override it?

I would like to keep the [all caps PEP8 convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) for constants.

---

**Sample Code**

```py
from abc import ABC


class BaseClass(ABC):
    """Some abstract base class."""

    # How do I force children to override this?
    CONST_CLASS_ATTR = "base"


class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    """Child class."""

    CONST_CLASS_ATTR = "child"
```

---

**Potential Solutions**

There is a very similar question already on here: [Abstract attributes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2736255/11163122)

However, all the answers seem to be workarounds.  I am wondering, is there a simpler way?

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58321197/11163122

Instructs to use two decorators: `abstractmethod` + `property`

- Pros: Linter informs me if child class doesn't implement `CONST_CLASS_ATTR`, and cannot instantiate at runtime due to it being abstract
- Cons: Linter (`pylint`) now complains `invalid-name`, and I would like to keep the constants have all caps naming convention

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class AnotherBaseClass(ABC):
    """Some abstract base class."""

    @abstractmethod
    @property
    def CONST_CLASS_ATTR(self) -> str:
        return "base"


class AnotherChildClass(AnotherBaseClass):
    """Child class."""

    @property
    def CONST_CLASS_ATTR(self) -> str:
        return "child"
```

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55544173/11163122

Instructs to use the dunder method `__init_subclass__`.  This is better, as my linter no longer complains, but it's less obvious.

- Pros: Linter no longer complains about `invalid-name`, and cannot instantiate at runtime due to raising a `NotImplementedError`
- Cons: Linter no longer warns if child class doesn't implement `CONST_CLASS_ATTR`.  Also, this seems verbose to me

```py
from abc import ABC


class YetAnotherBaseClass(ABC):
    """Some abstract base class."""

    CONST_CLASS_ATTR: str

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'CONST_CLASS_ATTR'):
            raise NotImplementedError(
                f"Class {cls} lacks required CONST_CLASS_ATTR class attribute.")


class YetAnotherChildClass(YetAnotherBaseClass):
    """Child class."""

    CONST_CLASS_ATTR = "child"
```

I am using Python 3.6

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I have been looking for this for a while, and I am glad that it is not only my concern:). This question definitely deserves more attention, I was personally surprised that it wasn't taken by linters into account since naming constants with CAPS is  a PEP convention.

Answer (score 2):

I think the property decorator approach is the cleanest. Just silence pylint:

```
@abstractmethod
@property
def CONST_CLASS_ATTR(self) -> str:  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    return "base"
```

This will only silence the warning for this specific method and its overrides.