# Explicitly require attribute in descendent of python base class

Tags: python, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class of which I'm only showing a small portion here, to illustrate my issue.

The abstract base class `A` below has a property `onemore` that uses the instance attribute `val`. Below it are subclasses `B` and `C`, which provide this attribute in distinct (but both valid) ways.

So far, so good:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @property
    def onemore(self) -> int:
        return self.val + 1


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._val = value

    val = property(lambda self: self._val)


class C(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.val = value


b = B(32)
b.onemore  # 33
c = C(54)
c.onemore  # 55
```

Now here is my question: **is there a way to define `A` in such a way, that it's more clear that the subclasses need to implement `val`?** As it's defined above, this is hard to miss, esp. if `A` has many more methods.

I tried this:

```py
class A(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def val(self) -> int:
        ...

    @property
    def onemore(self) -> int:
        return self.val + 1
```

This definition is too strict, though: I don't want to demand that the subclasses implement `val` as a property, I just want to require them to have it as a (readable) attribute. In other words, I want `C` to be a valid subclass, which is not the case here: this definition does not work with how `C` provides `self.val`. (`TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract method val`).

Any ideas?

PS I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2736255/2302262), which is similar, but doesn't solve the TypeError I'm getting.

Comment: I think `@abstractmethod` is the only canonical approach that comes to mind unfortunately

Comment: You can't simultaneously benefit from the strictness imposed by `ABC` and `abstractmethod` while also demanding more flexibility than those tools can provide. There is nothing you won't be able to do by simply always having `val` be a property. Bending over backwards to avoid using `property` would result in poor design for the sole purpose of avoiding having to write `def val` a bit more than you'd like to.

Comment: I see, thanks for that comment. I was trying to provide flexibility for devs who are implementing the subclasses and also to avoid breaking compatibility with existing implementations. But I guess that's not possible then.