# How to create an abstract attribute for an abstract class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abc

I already found some similar question where they try to create abstract attributes and they all suggest using `@property` and `@abc.abstractmethod` to achieve that like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736255/abstract-attributes-in-python). There are many similar topics but I cant find a way to do it without using the `@property` decorator. The reason that I don't want to use it is because I don't want to create `setter` and `getter` methods in my concrete classes. I simply want to enforce that my concrete classes will have a specific attribute for example `self.filter_name` which holds an encrypted version of the class's name.

This is my abstract class at the moment with the `@property` and `@abc.abstractmethod` decorators:

```
import abc
from typing import List

class DataFilter:
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def filter_name(self)-> str:
        """Returns the filter name encrypted"""
        pass
```

If I do the above and simply try to set my `self.filter_name` attribute in my concrete class to a specific value I get an `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. I wish to only have something like `self.filter_name = "blabla"` in my concrete class.

Comment: what you want is a class method, which has cls input not self

Comment: have you tried using @classmethod and @abstractmethod?

Comment: provide the line where you have error

Comment: @Mahsirat How does replacing the property with a class method help? The OP seems to be trying to simulate abstract "attributes" (which the `ABCMeta` does not provide).

Comment: @Mahsirat no I ll try now. The error is exactly when I try to assign a value to the self.filter_name attribute but probably you are right let me check.

Comment: Keep in mind that `ABCMeta` doesn't care *what* the subclass assigns to the name `filter_name`, as long as it assigns *something*. The name `abstractmethod` is more aspirational than prescriptive.

Comment: So using @classmethod is not the answer I think. It does eliminate the error message but also does nothing to enforce that the concrete class implements the self.filter_name. If I dont implement it I get no errors. So that doesn't work

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the reply! When you say that the `abstractmethod` does not care what I assign you refer to enforcing the type ? I know it doesnt do type enforcing at least I want to enforce the existence of it. But thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: For example, `class B(DataFilte): filter_name = 3` would be sufficient to *instantiate* `B`, though `B` certainly won't work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to enforce this is not with `abstractmethod`, but via `__init_subclass__`.

```
class DataFilter:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
       super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
       try:
           cls.filter_name
       except AttributeError:
           raise TypeError("Can't instantiate class DataFilter without name 'filter_name'")
```

You can perform additional tests on the value of `cls.filter_name` if it is present.