# Python - how to make abstract class constants?

Tags: python, oop

What is the python way of defining abstract class constants?

For example, if I have this abstract class:

```py
class MyBaseClass(SomeOtherClass, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    CONS_A: str
    CONS_B: str
```

So, the type checker/"compiler" (at least Pycharm's one) doesn't complain about the above.
But if I inherit it to another class and don't implement `CONS_A` and `CONS_B`, it doesn't complain either:

```py
class MyChildClass(MyBaseClass):
    pass
```

What is the python way of enforcing (the much we can with a duck-type language) implementation of `MyBaseClass` to actually implement `CONS_A` and `CONS_B`?

Bonus question: once I can enforce, how can I only enforce for non-abstract classes? I suppose it should be the same answer as the main question. But, I might be wrong. So, for example:

```py
# "compiler" should not complain
class MyChildAbstractClass(MyBaseClass):
    pass

# here it must complain if I don't implement `CONS_A` and `CONS_B`
class MyChildImplementationClass(MyChildAbstractClass):
    pass
```

Obs: I am aware of `@abstractmethod`, but I didn't find a solution for abstract class constants.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Abstract attributes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736255/abstract-attributes-in-python) Specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53417582/12479639) answer.

Comment: Python doesn't really have a concept of constants other than a naming convention.

Comment: Thanks, @Axe319. I'll check the answers. What do you mean by "Python doesn't really have a concept of constants other than a naming convention"? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure. The naming convention for constants is all capital letters, such as you have with `CONS_A`. However, Python doesn't enforce this in any way or treat it differently than any other class variables. I only mention this because if you come across a solution for abstract class attributes, they would be functionally identical.