# Mandatory overriding of fields/methods?

Tags: python

How do you specify in a Python parent class that certain fields/methods need to be overridden in the child classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151212/equivalent-of-notimplementederror-for-fields-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could raise a `NotImplementedError`:

```
def my_method(self, arg):
    raise NotImplementedError('Implement me')
```

For properties, you can use the `@property` decorator:

```
@property
def my_property(self):
    raise NotImplementedError('Implement me as well')
```

Comment: Yes, that should take care of a method, but what about fields?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module.

However, a simpler alternative is just to define a stub implementation that does nothing, or raises `NotImplementedError`.