# How can I throw an error when an attribute is accessed in JS?

Tags: javascript, decorator

I'd like to have an attribute throw an error if it's not defined, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151212/equivalent-of-notimplementederror-for-fields-in-python). Each of the answers to that question suggest using Python's `@property` decorator to raise an exception if the field isn't defined. How can I do that in JS?

EDIT:

I'm hoping for the equivalent of:

```
var MyObj = {
  method: function(){
    throw new Error('This method is not implemented');
  }
};
```

...but closer to:

```
var MyObj = {
  attribute: throw new Error('This attribute is not defined');
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can be broken down into two parts,

```
var myObj = {}; // just an example, could be a prototype, etc
```

**How can I add a non-enumerable property to an *Object*?**

This is done with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'foo', {get: function () {/* see next part */}});
```

I defined a *getter*, so you'll see the error message without needing to use `()` to invoke the function.

**How can I throw an error?**

This is as simple as using the [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) statement. *JavaScripts* closest [*Error*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) type to what you're looking for is most likely a [*ReferenceError*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError).

```
throw new ReferenceError("Subclasses should implement this!");
```

Comment: I was trying to use your solution until I realized that ``Object.defineProperty`` doesn't work with IE < 9, which I unfortunately need to support.

Comment: How far back do you need support for? I think IE8 might have `myObject.__defineGetter__` which you could use as a fallback (you'd have to check it does support it). This would mean it is enumerable but still works as a getter. If you want to go any further into the history books then you'll need a new way of looking up your properties (see [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6512201/1615483))